# PIL.save() not saving different quality versions of image

Tags: python, optimization, python-imaging-library

I want to save an image as 'JPEG' with different quality settings, to then load it again, and read out the quantization matrices. They matrices should be different for each quality parameter.

The following code should do that:

```
from PIL import Image

im_path = '~/Pictures/Origianl.JPG' # path to original image
im_path_tmp = '~/Pictures/DifferentQuality_' # trunk of path to images of lower quality

im = Image.open(im_path) # load original image

qs = {} # empty dictionary to save quantization matrices
qs['orig'] = im.quantization[0] # also remember q-matrix of original image

for i, qual in enumerate(range(100,-1,-10)): # run over 10 different quality parameters
    curr_path = im_path_tmp + str(qual) + '.JPG' # each image gets its own path
    print('iteration: {:2d}, curr_quality={:03d},curr_path={}'.format(i,qual,curr_path))
    im.save(curr_path, 'JPEG', qualilty=qual) # save image: quality-parameter is set!
    tmp = Image.open(curr_path) # load image again
    qs[qual] = tmp.quantization[0] # read out q-matrix and save to dict
    del tmp
    del curr_path

print()

for key, value in qs.items(): # show all q-matrices
    print('{}:\n\t{}'.format(key,value[0:32]))
```

I expect now 10 different q-matrices. Though they are all identical:

```
orig:
    array('B', [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 10, 8, 8, 8])
100:
    array('B', [8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26])
90:
    array('B', [8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26])
80:
    array('B', [8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26])
70:
    array('B', [8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26])
60:
    array('B', [8, 6, 6, 7, 6, 5, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 9, 8, 10, 12, 20, 13, 12, 11, 11, 12, 25, 18, 19, 15, 20, 29, 26, 31, 30, 29, 26])

# and so on ...
```

Note that it is changed at from orignal to all others. 
If I save it manually, like in an python-interpreter, it works, for some strange reasons:

```
In [90]: im.save('~/Pictures/manual.JPG', 'JPEG', quality=70)
In [91]: tmp = Image.open('~/Pictures/manual.JPG')
In [92]: tmp.quantization[0]

Out[92]: array('B', [10, 7, 7, 8, 7, 6, 10, 8, 8, 8, 11, 10, 10, 11, 14, 24, 16, 14, 13, 13, 14, 29, 21, 22, 17, 24, 35, 31, 37, 36, 34, 31, 34, 33, 38, 43, 55, 47, 38, 41, 52, 41, 33, 34, 48, 65, 49, 52, 57, 59, 62, 62, 62, 37, 46, 68, 73, 67, 60, 72, 55, 61, 62, 59])
```

Why is the behavior different, if done manually.
My best guess is, that someting is optimized by the interpreter. If so, how can I switch this off? I'm running ipython as interpreter with Anaconda python 3.6.1, it that's of any help.

Comment: there is a typo in "quality" in your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ch7kor who pointed out that there is a typo in the signature of the saving function. I pass "qual**IL**ity" instead of "quality"

That solves my actual question.

And raises the next question, why no error is thrown. I doubt that this parameter (with typo) exists in the function's signature...

Comment: A little late to the discussion, but the reason it didn't throw an error is because that specific function quietly ignores bad parameters. 

From Github:
Keyword options can be used to provide additional instructions
        to the writer. If a writer doesn't recognise an option, it is
        silently ignored. The available options are described in the
        :doc:`image format documentation
        <../handbook/image-file-formats>` for each writer.